# ElasticSearch. How can I get one document without counting all documents by filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get any document by a filter if it exists and I do not want ElasticSearch to count how many documents fit this filter.

Example, there are docs:

```
{"name": "dima", "age": 15},
{"name": "amid", "age": 15}
```

I want one document (size=1) where age is 15, I don't want ElasticSearch to waste time counting all

I do not need this:

```
"hits": {
     "total": {
       "value": 2,
       ...
     },
```

Comment: can you share an example to make it clear?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja done

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/collapse-search-results.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add a size field to tell Elastic how many docs to return, if you'd only like 1 then you can just use 1 in the size field. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html

For example:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "age": "15"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can just specify the size in the query string params
my-index/_search?size=1

I understand that this is not exactly what you want, because you'd rather Elastic just stop looking as soon as it finds the first one,  but don't think that is a possibilty .. check out the conversation on Elastic here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-stop-searching-on-first-match/15507/3